# Set Windows Service Login to a GMSA Account

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a service that gets created by a third party vendor that every time an instance of this software gets installed I have to manually go in and change the login account to a GMSA account.

By default this service is created with the logon account as local system. When I run the below Powershell code I get a return value of 21 where there is an invalid parameter:

'''

```
$ServiceObject  = get-wmiobject -Class Win32_Service -filter "Name='$ServiceName'"
$ServiceObject.StopService() | out-null

# Change logon as settings
$ServiceObject.Change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$GMSAServiceAccount,$null,$null,$null,$null) 
$ServiceObject.StartService()
```

'''

I did find in my testing if I manually made the Service Account logon as a different user on the same domain as the GMSA. Then run the above script it runs successfully. Is there another step I'm missing?

Comment: I think you can't set the Password parameter to `$null`. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/change-method-in-class-win32-service) Specify NULL if you are not changing the password. Specify an empty string if the service account has no password.

Comment: If I change it to instead it still does not work. $ServiceObject.Change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$GMSAServiceAccount,"",$null,$null,$null)

Comment: But my original code works if I manually change the logon for that service to some other domain account and then run the script.

Comment: Then.. does your `$GMSAServiceAccount` have a password or not? If there is a password, you need to put that in

Comment: It does not have a password

Comment: Something else to note. If I use the above script to make the logon account a domain account that has a password and I put in both it does not work still. It seems like by default it is stuck only looking for local computer accounts.

Comment: Please provide content of ´$GMSAServiceAccount`

Comment: Is it a fact that you still use PS v3 or did you tag it by accident?

Comment: If you manually set user1 as the service account and then manually set user2 as the service account, does your script then work, if you try to set user1 by script?

Comment: Does `$GMSAServiceAccount` looks like`domain\samaccountname$`?

Comment: @Nathan I do not have an elaborate answer but this is something to do with the local account not having the permission to use the GMSA and thus not being able to set the service account. Before even trying to change the service account, just try this simple statement : `Test-AdServiceAccount -Identity 'GMSAIdentity'` (Your identity is the GMSA name without the domain so something like `YourIdentity$`) From the local account, you'll get an error right away. From the AD account which you say it work, the test statement will return `$true`.

Comment: If I login on that server and simply change the logon account for that server to domain\gmsa account and clear out the garbage encrypted password characters it accepts that and works. But if I try to set it with powershell when running powershell as an Admin I get a return error of 21 or "Invalid Parameter"

Answer (score 1):

We use this piece of code to configure gMSA accounts with services:

```
$serviceName = 'myService' 
$ServiceObject = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='$serviceName'" 
$ServiceObject.StopService() | out-null

# Change logon as settings
$ServiceObject.Change($null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null, "$env:USERDOMAIN\$gMSA_Name$", $null, $null, $null, $null)
$ServiceObject.StartService()
```

Make sure that there is an `$` behind the gMSA account name. This indicates it is a gMSA account.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I am still getting a ReturnValue of 21 or "Invalid Parameter" when doing the Change as noted above.

Comment: This bit `Make sure that there is an $ behind the gMSA account name. This indicates it is a gMSA account.` is what made it work for me.

$ServiceObject.Change($null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null, "mydomain.local\gMSA-AccountName$", "", $null, $null, $null)