# Creating a service with a gMSA account using New-Service

Tags: powershell, windows-services, gmsa

Is it possible to use the [New-Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-service?view=powershell-7.2) command to create a service using a gMSA account? I tried creating the credentials with a blank password but it fails because [ConvertTo-SecureString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertto-securestring?view=powershell-7.2) expects the string to not be empty.

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "" -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("DOMAIN\dev-user$", $password)
New-Service -Name Service -BinaryPathName C:\Service -StartupType Automatic -Credential $credential
Start-Service -Name "Service"
```

I then tried setting the string to just `a` to see if it even cared about the password since this is a gMSA account and I got this error.

```
New-Service : Service '(Service)' cannot be created due to the following error: The account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account name specified
```

EDIT: I know there are other ways I could accomplish this like `Wmi-Object` or `sc.exe` but I wanted to see if there was a means to do this via `New-Service` just to see if I am missing something or doing something wrong.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64275849/15339544

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon trying to see if this can be done without WMI using the New-Service command. I know I could also do this with sc.exe but was hoping for a definitive answer on if there is a way to make the New-Service command work with gMSA accounts.

Comment: I'm not sure Windows allow you to create the service using the gMSA, I think you need to create it first using a service account or the same logged on account and then update the service to use the gMSA which is what the linked answer I posted is doing

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I found a means to do it locally though not sure this works with older versions of powershell/windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer for how to make a new blank `SecureString` and this worked

```
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("DOMAIN\dev-user$", (New-Object System.Security.SecureString))
New-Service -Name Service -BinaryPathName C:\Service -StartupType Automatic -Credential $credential
Start-Service -Name "Service"
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6839924/1162324) assisted me in figuring out how to do this.

EDIT: Wanted to add this did not working on 2012r2 but worked on Windows 10 and 2016

Comment: nice finding! glad it worked

Comment: This didn't work for me on Windows Server 2022, failing with the following error:

New-Service : Service 'ServiceDisplayName (ServiceShortName)' cannot be created due
to the following error: The account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account name
specified

Comment: I was able to do so in 2 steps: `New-Service ... | Set-Service -Credential $credential`

Comment: `-Credential` is only available in pwsh (as Info for others stumbling over this)